# Не запускается файл .py в питоне через командную строку

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Изучаю python и столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Не могу запустить программу на командной строке через питон, выдаёт ошибку "no such file or directory ".

[image: Ошибка]

Но, когда я просто открываю код как файл - всё работает как надо.

[image: Всё нормально]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас файл называется **pog.py.py**

Тут 2 варианта:

1. уберите одно `.py` в названии и запускайте скрипт `python pog.py`.
2. ничего не убирайте. запускайте как `python pog.py.py`.

*Предпочитетелен способ 1.*

Comment: Не помогло, всё та же ошибка осталась.

Comment: @Kassiy, Напишите `dir` и посмотрите, какие файлы там находятся.

Comment: Теперь всё в порядке, надо было строку командную перезапустить ещё. Спасибо.